# Is it possible to use an XCom from an operator parameter without using Jinja?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

Is it possible to pass an XCom to an operator parameter without using a Jinja template? I have a dict stored in an XCom and I need to pass it to an Operator that receives a dict, and using Jinja I can only return the XCom as string. i.e:

```
def push_xcom(ti):
    ti.xcom_push(key='my_xcom', value={"key": "value"})
    
with DAG(...) as dag:
    start = PythonOperator(task_id='dp_start', python_callable=push_xcom)
    
    middle = MyOperator(task_id='dp_middle',
        parameter='{{ti.xcom_pull(key="my_xcom")}}'
    )

    start >> middle
```

I know is possible using task.output as a parameter and store the Xcom using return in the python callable, but this create a dependency between tasks and I need to use the XCom in another task... For example:

```
def push_xcom(ti):
    return {"key": "value"}


def pull_xcom(input):
    print(f'XCom: {input}')


with DAG(...) as dag:
    start = PythonOperator(task_id='dp_start',
                           python_callable=push_xcom)
    
    middle = MyOperator(task_id='dp_middle',
                        parameter=start.output)

    end = PythonOperator(task_id='dp_start', python_callable=pull_xcom,
                         op_kwargs={'input': start.output})

    start >> middle >> end
```

[image: task dependencies]

So is it possible to do it without using Jinja Templates or task.output? Or by passing an XCom to more than one task will I irremediably create dependencies between them (visible from the Graph view)?

Thanks in advance.